# Comparar horas en Java

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy aprendiendo Java y intento hacer un programa que controle las horas de una jornada laboral. La idea es: le pido al usuario una hora de inicio(HH:mm) (de su trabajo por ejemplo) y una hora fin (HH:mm). Eso lo guardo para poder operar con ello después.(no sé muy bien como pedir una hora al usuario sin hacerlo como String, ya que si lo hago como String me puede colar cualquier cosa.Tiene que hacer alguna API para poder trabajar con horas, es decir comparar, sumar, restar,... He visto la Date y no me aclaro...

Lo que necesito comprobar es que la hora fin menos la hora inicio no excede de 15 horas, es decir su jornada no debe ser superior a esas 15 horas. (Esto no sé como hacerlo..).
Después necesito sacar bloques o periodos entre esas horas y operar con las horas, separar, agrupar,...
Solo me interesa trabajar con horas y minutos, no me hace falta el día, mes ni año. Es para jornada de un día.
Esto es lo que tengo por ahora:
A ver si alguien me puede echar un cable porfa. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner
        System.out.println("Introduzca la hora de inicio: (hh:mm)");
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(in.next());
        System.out.println("Introduzca la hora de finalización: (hh:mm)");
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(in.next());

        int minutes = (int) ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end);

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        if (minutes > (60 * 15)) {//sobrelímite de jornada:
            System.out.println("Límte de jornada!");
            System.out.println("Sobrepasa las 15 horas!!!");
            System.in.read();
        } else {//jornada correcta:
            System.out.println("Límite de 15 horas en la jornada: OK");
            System.out.println("rango de minutos: " + minutes);
            //más cosas..
            //mostramos horas de trabajo total:
            int workhours = minutes / 60;//pasar a horas los minutos trabajados(para mostrarlas)
            if (minutes <= 60 && minutes > 0) {
                System.out.println("Horas de trabajo: " + workhours + " hora.");
                System.out.println("\nPosible trabajo:");
                System.out.println("1 hora de conducción.");
                System.in.read();
            } else {
                if (minutes < 0) {
                    minutes += 60 * 24;
                }
                System.out.println("Horas de trabajo: " + workhours + " horas.");
                //mostramos los periodos:

                if (minutes > 45 && minutes <= 315) {//
                    System.out.println("\nPosible trabajo:");
                    System.out.println("Salida a las " + start + "h,");
                    System.out.println("4:30h de conducción,");
                    System.out.println("1 descanso de 45 min,");
                    System.out.println("fin de trabajo a las " + end + ".");
                    System.in.read();
                }
                if (minutes > 315 && minutes <= 630) {
                    System.out.println("\nPosible trabajo:");
                    System.out.println("Salida a las " + start + "h,");
                    System.out.println("4:30h de conducción,");
                    System.out.println("1 descanso de 45 min,");
                    System.out.println("4:30h de conducción,");
                    System.out.println("1 descanso de 45 min.");
                    System.in.read();
                }
                if (minutes > 630 /*&& minutes<=690*/) {
                    System.out.println("\nPosible trabajo:");
                    System.out.println("Salida a las " + start + "h,");
                    System.out.println("4:30h de conducción,");
                    System.out.println("1 descanso de 45 min,");
                    System.out.println("4:30h de conducción,");
                    System.out.println("1 descanso de 45 min,");
                    System.out.println("60 minutos de conducción.");
                    System.out.println("Alcanzado el límite de 9h de conducción.");
                    System.in.read();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Horas de inicio/fin no válidas!");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pide la hora como String y para validarla tan solo intenta parsearla. Para esto, usa `LocalTime` que guarda horas solamente (con o sin segundos/nano segundos).

```
    LocalTime entrada = null;
    LocalTime salida = null;    

    System.out.print("Hora de ingreso: ");
    String strIngreso = kb.next();
    System.out.print("\nHora de salida: ");
    String strSalida = kb.next();
    try {
       ingreso = LocalTime.parse(strIngreso);
       salida = LocalTime.parse(strSalida);
       // otra lógica
    } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
       // la hora de entrada o salida es inválida,
       // informar al usuario y volver a pedirla
       pedirHoras();
    }
```

Para comprobar el tiempo entre dos horas, por medio de `ChronoUnit` obtén la diferencia en minutos entre ambas horas (objetos LocalTime) y la comparas con `60 * 15` que vendrían a ser los minutos equivalentes a 15 horas:

```
    int minutes = (int) ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ingreso, salida);

    if(minutes > (15 * 60)) {
        // alerta, ¡estás explotando a tus empleados!
    }
```

Un ejemplo más real:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso: ");
            LocalTime ingreso = LocalTime.parse(kb.next());
            System.out.print("Ingrese la fecha de salida: ");
            LocalTime salida  = LocalTime.parse(kb.next());

            int minutes = (int) ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ingreso, salida);
            if(minutes > (60 * 15)) {
                System.out.println("¡Estás explotando a tus empleados!");
            }
        } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Fecha de ingreso o salida inválida");
        }
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Ingrese la fecha de ingreso: 08:00
Ingrese la fecha de salida: 23:01
¡Estás explotando a tus empleados!
```

Comment: Tu codigo es incorrecto, porque no toma en cuenta los minutos, y porque no toma en cuenta horarios que cruzan medianoche. Ademas, el parser aceptaria entradas con formatos no esperados (segundos, puntos decimales para fracccion de segundos)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces nada de la API calendar, ni Date ni otra que creo que había, no? Es que he estado buscando y leyendo y he visto tantas cosas que ya no sabía ni lo que quería hacer.
Voy a ver si sigo tu ejemplo, aunque luego tengo que hacer los periodos...
Otra cosa cuando hacer el import de java.time.* ¿porque luego haces los otros dos? ¿no se supone que por jerarquía ya estarían importados?
Disculpadme, pero soy nuevo y llevo una movida mental de conceptos y cosas con el lenguaje "que pa que"

Comment: No. La sintaxis `import paquete.*` importa **solamente las clases** dentro de dicho paquete. No importa subpaquetes. En realidad no es complicado usar esta API ni otras que tienes a disposición, tan solo es cuestión de lógica. No te aturdes mucho, lee una cosa a la vez que si no, luego te confundes y te frustras.

Comment: Arreglaste el primer problea que te señalé, pero no el segundo. Ejemplo: el usuario entra a las 21:00 y sale a las 3:00

Comment: Sí, es verdad, cuando pongo ese rango de horas me sale en negativo. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo? bueno eso y la parte de mostrar la info, que me parece super cutre hacerlo así, pero es lo que se me ocurre con lo que sé... 
//pongo el código en la pregunta que aquí no cabe. :S

Comment: @EricFerrando Mira mi respuesta

Comment: ¿Deseas la solución exacta? Entonces, busca en otro lado. Te he dado un muy buen comienzo para que tan solo investigues un poco más y soluciones tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada el codigo que te voy a pasar sirve convirtiendo una cadena de texto String a Date por lo que yo suguiero que empieces a ver el uso dejcalendar el cual te deja obtener la fecha y la hora, apartir de eso ya solo tendria que convertir a string la hora y usar el siguiente codigo que te presento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor poner el código en formato texto.

Comment: Hola @Jose. Por favor coloca el código en texto. Si tienes problemas con el formato, puedes ponerle una bandera a tu publicación y con gusto te ayudaré.

Comment: Hola, por favor coloca tu codigo para que sea mas facil.

Answer (score -2):

No tiene mucho sentido usar una librería de fechas/horas para algo tan simple.

Para ingresar los datos tienes dos opciones:

- Pedir hora y minuto por separado (más recomendable en el caso de un formulario)
- Pedir hora minuto en string separado por ":" , separarlos con .split()

En ambos casos, conviertes ambos campos a `int` (validando), y luego conviertes todo a minutos y computas la diferencia. Por ejemplo:

```
  int hora1,min1,hora2,min2; // ...
  int horamin1 = hora1*60 + min1;
  int horamin2 = hora2*60 + min2;
  int totalminutos = horamin2 - horamin1;
  if(totalminutos < 0 ) totalminutos += 60*24; // intervalo corta medianoche
  boolean masde15horas = totalminutos > 15*60;
```

Comment: Lo que **NO** tiene sentido es no usar una API que resuelve tus necesidades. Para eso se han creado, para usarlas.

Comment: En desacuerdo - con el argumento y con la actitud. A crecer.

Comment: Vale, entonces, olvidemos las APIs que nos dan los lenguajes, olvidemos JSF, Spring, Struts, Play, GWT, Vaadin y utilicemos Servlets y las miles de librerías existentes para escibir una solución que ya fue dada anteriormente y que nos proveen. Reinventar la rueda no te hace mejor desarrollador. Pero sí, para practicar lógica sirve tu solución.